# Converting the square root sign from string to char

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion

In order to get the char version of "\u221A" (aka the square root sign), would I just do the following:

```
String op = "\u221A";
char operator = op.charAt(0);

operator = '\u221A';
```

The last part doesn't seem right. Just wondering how I'd go about doing that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What "*doesn't seem right*" actually mean?  Have you tried it?

Comment: In Java, unicode escapes are resolved before the source is even parsed.  So your second method is perfectly fine; it becomes a literal character 221A.  Fun fact: you can write valid Java source consisting entirely of unicode escapes.

Comment: @kjkrum You have an interesting definition of fun.

Comment: First part(1,2 lines) and last part(4 line) does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hex literal directly seems simpler than either of the approaches you state, although they all have the same effect.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String op = "\u221A";
    char operator1 = op.charAt(0);
    char operator2 = '\u221a';
    char operator3 = 0x221a;
    System.out.println(operator1 == operator2);
    System.out.println(operator2 == operator3);
  }
}
```